# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, console.log

**Help me please understand and fix this error:**

I'm trying to get data from the local server and as a result I see this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
```

("Postman" and the browser get and show me the response correctly)
The full err: [Screeshot console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIniY.jpg)
I use Angular 4.3.1

My code looks like this:

**SERVICE**

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http/src/enums';

export class User {
  constructor(public id: number,
            public name: string,
            public age: number,
            public occupation: string) {
  }
}

@Injectable()
  export class UserService {
  private userUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/';

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

getUsers(name?: string): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.userUrl}users`, {params: {name}})
        .map((res: Response) => { return res.json() })
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 
    'Server error'));
}
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import {User, UserService} from './user.service';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './user-list.component.html'
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    users: Observable<User[]>;
    public search: FormControl = new FormControl();
    constructor(private service: UserService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.users = this.search.valueChanges
           .startWith('')
           .debounceTime(800)
           .distinctUntilChanged()
           .switchMap(name => this.service.getUsers(name));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you remove this bit error.json().error    and check the outcome? From the console output it seems to be landing on the catch branch

Comment: yea it looks like its hitting your catch

Comment: @HugoNoro After I changed this line to .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
I see in the console 'Server error'

Comment: Correct. OK so that’s what I was expecting. So your issue has nothing to do with the return of the json. It seems you’re getting an issue retrieving the data and for some reason it seems that no error is being sent from the server

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the screenshot you’re having some issue retrieving the data from the server. Due to this you’re falling into the catch branch and trying to do a json on an empty error.

Check your server and why it’s not returning an error when the call is failing. That might give you a clue why the call on the API is not working.

But as per your initial question this has nothing to do with the response in the success branch of the observable. Your code is correct. You have to figure out why the call to your API is failing.

**Edit**

On a closer look I noticed that your request is not in the proper format you should be doing something like

```
getUsers(name?: string): Observable<User[]> {
    let myParams  = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.append('name', name);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ params: myParams });

return this.http.get(`${this.userUrl}users`, options)
    .map((res: Response) => { return res.json() })
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 
'Server error'));
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I can not get data at all. Tried to specify other resources, which obviously work correctly. Do I need to set any mandatory headers when I send a request?

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to include a bit more of detail